# Powershell NAS CIFS share free space

Tags: powershell, size, nas, cifs

I am trying to retrieve the following information using PowerShell: free space on a CIFS NAS share. Tried `PS-Drive` but there must be a better way to do it than to persist a mounted drive:

```
New-PSDrive –Name "R" –PSProvider FileSystem –Root "\\serverName\Folder" -Persist

Get-PSDrive R | Select-Object Free

Remove-PSDrive -Name "R"
```

Is there a better way to retrieve free space for a NAS CIFS volume?

Answer (score -1):

If your NAS vendor supplies a SMI-S provider, then you can install it and use the Powershell storage module, `get-virtualdisk` cmdlet. I know that NetApp and EMC, for example, both have SMI-S providers.

BTW, when you say, "a better way", better in what respect? An SMI-S provider is "better" in the sense that it can provide a lot more info, than querying a mapped drive (whether persistent or not) could and a lot more actions (provision a new LUN, take snapshots, etc.). But it's not better in the sense that there are more steps to using it (download provider, install it, configure it, load PS storage module).